# C# click html button with same id

Tags: c#, html, automation, click, send

Can somebody help me.
I need to know how can i automate a form with a webbrowser and just click the button containing the "Report" text on.
i cant do it with ID because they all have "send" ID.

```
this.form.target='';
        this.form.action='/foglioorario.php';
        this.form.submit();"><OPTION value='0'></OPTION><OPTION value='1'>Tirana</OPTION></SELECT></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><input name='azione' value='Importa Curva' type='button' class='TbStyle' onclick="on_click('form1', 'importForecast.php', 'import')"/></td>
                    <td colspan='2'><span style='margin-right:20px'>
                        Alpha:<input name='alpha' id='alpha' type='TEXT' maxlength='3' value='95' style='width:25px'/>% 
                        </span>  
                        <span style='margin-right:20px'>
                        TMS:<input name='tms' id='tms' type='TEXT' maxlength='3' value='290' style='width:25px'/>
                        </span>                 
                        <span>                
                        <input type='submit' id='send' name='send' value='Compara curva' class='TbStyle'/>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                        <input type='submit' id='send' name='send' value='Export CC' class='TbStyle' title='Click per export Excel'/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type='submit' id='send' name='send' value='Report' class='TbStyle'/>
                    <input type='submit' id='send' name='send' value='Export R' class='TbStyle' title='Click per export Excel'/></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' id='send' name='send' value='Riepilogo Sett' class='TbStyle'/>
                    <input type='submit' id='send' name='send' value='Export S' class='TbStyle' title='Click per export Excel'/></td>
                    <td>
                        <span>Pause: <input type='checkbox' name='chkpause' /></span>
                        <span style='padding-left:10px'>Disp.Strao: <input type='checkbox' name='chkStrao' /></span>

                </tr>
```

Comment: there is an odd mix of javascript and html on your sample can you pls explain what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what you're saying, let me know if this works out for you.

```
IHTMLElementCollection buttonCol = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (IHTMLElement btn in buttonCol)
{
    if (btn.getAttribute("value") == "Report")
    {
        btn.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer saved me, i just modified it a little and used it without mshtml.
This is how im using it:

```
        WebBrowser wb = webBrowser1;
        var doc = wb.Document;
        HtmlElementCollection el = doc.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement btn in el)
        {
            if (btn.GetAttribute("value") == "Report")
            {
                btn.InvokeMember("click");
                break;
            }
        }
```

u're great thnx